# frequency of letters at position in string

Tags: string, r, perl, frequency-distribution

I want to count the frequency of 4 letters at every position across strings. The letters are A, T, G, C

```
TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTAT
TAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTA
TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTAC
TGAGAACTGAATTCCATAGG
```

desired output:

```
  Pos1  Pos2  Pos3  and so on. 
A 0     1
T 4     0
C 0     0
G 0     3
```

So far I have used an R package called Biostrings, which works, but I wonder if perl would do this?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: ... and why do you want to switch to Perl?

Comment: Perl will not *do it*, but you can *do it* in perl. But why?

Comment: In the past, such low quality questions would receive only at most a few down-votes but this here shows some unhealthy religious-like zeal. Let's examine if that's the community we want to be. OP may have a perfectly reasonable explanation why Perl is preferred language here. Let's keep an open mind, shall we.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, for

```
x = "TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTAT
TAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTA
TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTAC
TGAGAACTGAATTCCATAGG"
```

a [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) solution is

```
library(Biostrings)
consensusMatrix(DNAStringSet(strsplit(x, "\n")[[1]]))
```

which will be fast for millions of sequences.